# Missing mapsettings.ui while loading QGIS Cloud 3.1.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I have an issue with QGIS Cloud 3.1.8. The plugin installs nicely but doesn't load due to the following error message.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:/Users/ahmed/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\mapsettings.ui'

I was able to find the file *mapsettings.ui* on GitHub.

Should I save it and add it manually? Should I save it in a `.txt`-format? Is there perhaps a more elegant solution?

I'm not used to working with GitHub.

QGIS cloud was working fine before on the previous version 3.1.7 but when I updated it I had this issue.

QGIS v3.10.7
QGIS Cloud v3.1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the distribution file. We just published a fixed version 3.1.9 of the plugin. Please give it a try.

Comment: It's working now ! Cheers! Thanks for the great job you're doing